running in the external Console in Clion , close before the program ends
I am coding C in Clion and trying to run the program in the external console (from run ->Edi configuration -> External console)  , the problem is the console is closing before the program ends running  , what should  i do ?
i have no idea why the problem occurs

the problem is the console is closing before the program ends running - pretty sure it closes after the program ends running. Which it should do as long as it does not expect any input from the user. So if you want it to wait, then add some dummy input expectation, such as fgetc(stdin) in the end of your program.

yes   , it fixes the problem  , i remebers me of Pascal coding when you use readln () ; inorder to stop the console from closing
